# window.dispatchEvent doesn't work in Firefox, Safari or IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, cross-browser, iscroll

I need to force a resize of my browser window due to a promise that breaks IScroll on a very wide element (the problem is that I use a promise to change the width if promise succeeds). IScroll loads before the promise is finished and gets the with from the original element. The result is that I can only scroll as wide as the original element width, not the new width of the wider element loaded by the promise. If I manually resize the browser window, I can then scroll the full size.

I fixed this by changing IScroll's `maxScrollX` and `scrollerWidth` after the promise has loaded, but I also use an indicator that doesn't scroll all the way.

I try to fix this using `window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));` to force a resize of the window. My problem is that this works fine in Chrome, but breaks the scroll altogether in Firefox, Safari and IE. Is there some other way to force a resize of the window that is compatible with all browsers?

I tried the following browsers which doesn't work:

- Safari 5.1.4 (734.54.16)
- Firefox 45.0.2
- Edge 25.10586.0.0

Comment: `window.resizeTo(width, height)` will resize the window

Comment: @EaswarRaju `console.log(window.innerHeight); window.resizeTo(500, 500); console.log(window.innerHeight);` gave the same value in chrome in both console.logs. Even though width was not close to 500 before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answer myself:

```
$timeout(function() {
    var evt = $window.document.createEvent('UIEvents'); 
    evt.initUIEvent('resize', true, false, $window, 0); 
    $window.dispatchEvent(evt);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this - you should tag your response as the answer - just saved me a ton of time debugging this in IE!